# How can I effectively disarm mines?

Tags: let-it-die

I've only seen three ways to disarm mines so far.

1. Run *near* the mines, which starts the countdown.
2. Run *over* the mines, which immediately detonates them.
3. Shoot the mines with ranged weapons, which also immediately detonates them.

Unfortunately, I rarely travel with a ranged weapon. Is there an easy way to clear out minefields with 20+ mines in them? It takes pretty long to play chicken with each mine. Blowing up one mine also doesn't always blow up nearby mines. Is this the only way to get rid of all these mines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing one good way to detonate an entire minefield: You can jump over mines to trigger them without exploding them. Just be careful to time your jumps correctly and you can clear a field in a matter of seconds.

That or you can try to lure enemies into the field, although I find that's more hazardous than just jumping around the mines.